# PDF to Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, converters

I am stuck with trying to get a solution for my PDF import problems. I wrote a VBA code that converts/extracts the text from a PDF file into excel, I am trying to find a solution to make Excel leave out any tables or pictures that are in the PDF. Any advice or help will be of a great value. The code is below.
Sub Button1_Click()

```
    Option Explicit
    
Sub ImportPDFToExcel()
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim myPath      As Variant
    Dim acroApp     As Object
    Dim acroAVDoc   As Object
    Dim acroPDDoc   As Object
    Dim pageNum     As Integer
    Dim pageCount   As Integer
    Dim myText      As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim shtImport   As Worksheet
    Dim jsObj       As Object
    Dim wordCount   As Long
    
    'Select the PDF file to import
    myPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("PDF Files    (*.pdf), *.pdf")
    
    'Initialize the Acrobat objects
    Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set acroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    acroAVDoc.Open myPath, "Acrobat"
    
    'Get the PDDoc object from the AVDoc object
    Set acroPDDoc = acroAVDoc.GetPDDoc()
    
    'Initialize the JavaScript object
    Set jsObj = acroPDDoc.GetJSObject
    
    'Get the number of pages in the PDF file
    pageCount = acroPDDoc.GetNumPages()
    
    'Create a new worksheet for importing the PDF text
    Set shtImport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    shtImport.Name = "Imported PDF Ver2.2"
    
    'Loop through each page of the PDF file
    For i = 0 To pageCount - 1
        ' Get the number of words on the page
        wordCount = jsObj.getPageNumWords(i)
        
        ' Get the text from the JavaScript object
        For j = 0 To wordCount - 1
            myText = myText & " " & jsObj.getPageNthWord(i, j)
        Next j
        
        'Write the text to the worksheet
        shtImport.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = myText
        myText = ""
    Next i
    
    'Close the PDF file and release the Acrobat objects
    acroPDDoc.Close
    acroAVDoc.Close (1)
    acroApp.Exit
    Set acroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set acroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set acroApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "PDF Text imported successfully."
    
End Sub
```